# AWS KMS storing customer master key

Tags: amazon-kms

I know I'm missing something here but I'm struggling to understand the **customer master key** concept in AWS KMS. Below is the sample code.

Code to create master key:

```
`CreateKeyRequest req = new CreateKeyRequest();
CreateKeyResult result = kmsClient.createKey(req);
String customerMasterKey = result.getKeyMetadata().getKeyId();`
```

Code to create data key using customer master key:

```
`GenerateDataKeyRequest dataKeyRequest = new GenerateDataKeyRequest();
dataKeyRequest.setKeyId(customerMasterKey);
dataKeyRequest.setKeySpec("AES_128");
GenerateDataKeyResult dataKeyResult = kmsClient.generateDataKey(dataKeyRequest);`
```

Now as per my understanding, I need to use the master key to decrypt the encrypted data key every time I want to encrypt/decrypt some thing. Which means I need to store these two keys in some location. So if someone else can get access to these two keys, can they be able to decrypt my data using AWS encryption SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The master key never leaves AWS and is only accessible by someone with the appropriate access to your account and the key. If they have access to your account and with the appropriate rights to use the key then they can use the master key to encrypt/decrypt your data key. Remember the master key ID is not the actual key, therefore, being in possession of the key ID is not useful outside of the AWS.
2. You do not store both keys, the master key ID will always be viewable using the console, CLI or SDK(I assume since I have not used it).
3. The data key is not managed by the KMS service, therefore, you'll have to store it(after encrypting it with the master key) along with the encrypted data.

The answer to your question is... if it happens that an unauthorised individual has a copy of your master key ID and your encrypted data key, there's no way they can use that master key unless they also have access to your AWS user credentials with the appropriate rights to use that master key.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thando. But if you look at the second code block from my question, I just need master key id to generate a data key. And using those two keys I can encrypt/decrypt my data. I think I don't need aws user credentials for that operation?

Comment: @hareesh you do need AWS user credentials configured in a credentials file in your user directory. There is no way you can use the API without authentication.